# Understanding Blazor two-way binding

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor

I try to create a wrapper component around the `Select` component from Ant Blazor ui framework.

For this I read the [microsoft docs about two way binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components).

My wrapper seems to work as intended but when I do some logging I don't understand how it works under the hood.

This is the code for my wrapper :

```cs
<Select TItem="ClientTitleDto"
        TItemValue="int?"
        DataSource="@ClientTitleList"
        @bind-Value="@ChildValue"
        LabelName="@nameof(ClientTitleDto.Name)"
        ValueName="@nameof(ClientTitleDto.Id)">
</Select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private List<ClientTitreDto> ClientTitleList { get; set; } = new ();
    
    private int? ChildValue
    {
        get => Value;
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Set from child, value : {value}");
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var response = await ClientTitlesApi.GetAllAsync();
        ClientTitleList = response.Data;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Set from parent, value : {Value}");
    }
}
```

And this is the parent component :

```cs
<MyWrapper @bind-Value="@selectedID"/>

<Button OnClick="() => selectedID = 5">Change from parent</Button>

@code {
    private int? selectedID;
}
```

Everything works fine but I don't understand why.
This is the log when I select a value from the `Select` component inside my wrapper :

```
Set from child, value : 10
Set from parent, value : 10
```

Why do I get something from the parent? I expect the value to go from `Select` -> `Wrapper` -> `Parent` and not `Select` -> `Wrapper` -> `Parent` -> `Wrapper`.

The worst case is when I set the value directly from the parent :

```
Set from parent, value : 5
Set from child, value : 5
Set from parent, value : 5
```

Which in my understanding do `Parent` -> `Wrapper` -> `Select` -> `Wrapper` -> `Parent` -> `Wrapper`

Why this behaviour and how it doesn't end in a infinite loop then?

Answer (score 1):

I've re-written your code using standard components to build a minimal reproducible example to explore the behaviour you report.

The Component - MySelect.razor

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics;

<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value=ChildValue >
    @if(ChildValue is null)
    {
        <option disabled selected value=""> -- Select a Value -- </option>
    }
    @foreach(var option in options)
    {
        <option value="@option.Value">@option.Description</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private int? ChildValue
    {
        get => Value;
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Set from child, value : {value}");
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // dummy async behaviour
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Set from parent, value : {Value}");
    }

    public IEnumerable<OptionList> options = new List<OptionList>
    {
        new OptionList(1, "UK"),
        new OptionList(2, "France"),
        new OptionList(3, "Portugal"),
        new OptionList(4, "Spain"),
        new OptionList(5, "Italy"),
    };

    public record OptionList(int Value, string Description);
}
```

And the test page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

And this is the parent component :

<MySelect @bind-Value="@selectedID"/>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => selectedID = 5">Change from parent</button>
</div>

@code {
    private int? selectedID;
}
```

1. At startup `OnParametersSet` is called as the component renders with `Value` set to `null`.

```
Set from parent, value :
```

2. Select `France`.

The setter is called passing a value of 2 back to the parent - and logs the first message.
This sets `selectedID` to 2 in the parent.
The parent renders as the Callback is a UI event.
The bind value on `MySelect` has changed so the render also renders `MySelect`
`OnParametersSet` is run on `MySelect` - and logs the second message.

```
Set from child, value : 2
Set from parent, value : 2
```

3. Click the parent button.

This sets `selectedID` to 2 in the parent.
The parent renders as the button click is a UI event.
The bind value on `MySelect` has changed so the render also renders `MySelect`
`OnParametersSet` is run on `MySelect` - and logs the second message.

```
Set from parent, value : 5
```

This is all as expected.  The behaviour you report may well be caused by the Ant control, but I don't understand why, and it's not what I would expect?  Most people who answer questions on here are not third party component experts, so you'll probably need to ask Ant Design why.

Comment: Ok thx for your time, I will investigate the ant design component then.